# How do you convert a Python Decimal instance to a C++ double?

Tags: c++, boost-python

In Python itself, you'd write simply `float(f)` where `f` is a Python Decimal. That yields a `double` type (called a `float` in Python).

But I need to do this in `boost::python`. My code (abridged) is

```
double toDouble(boost::python::object obj)
{
    std::string type = boost::python::extract<std::string>(obj.attr("__class__").attr("__name__"));
    std::string module = boost::python::extract<std::string>(obj.attr("__class__").attr("__module__"));
    std::string cls = module + "." + type;

    if (cls == "decimal.Decimal"){
        double f = boost::python::extract<double>(obj);
        return f;
    }
    
    throw "Oops";
}
```

But I get an error

> No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type
> double from this Python object of type decimal.Decimal

How do I do this? I can't imagine it's complicated. Clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you need in the `if` block is

```
static boost::python::object builtins
    = boost::python::import("builtins");
static boost::python::object function 
    = boost::python::extract<boost::python::object>(builtins.attr("float"));
boost::python::object ret = function(obj);
double f = boost::python::extract<double>(ret);
```

I am indeed essentially using the Python function `float(obj)`.

And by the looks of things, you are already familiar with `boost::python::extract`.

`float` is a *built-in* python function. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html. So the first statement is the importing of the module containing the built-in functions. The second statement obtains the `float` function.

The third one calls it, on the lines of the Boost documentation "Calling Python Functions And Methods".

You might be able to pull this together to *register* this extraction, which probably, knowing the beautiful way in which Boost is designed, amounts to little more than specialising a template.